# simple putStrLn in Haskell/Yampa with arrows syntax

Tags: haskell, arrows, frp

i'm using Haskell with the Yampa FRP library which uses the arrows language extension.

how can i do a simple putStrLn in a SF?

```
mySF = proc x -> do
    y <- identity -< x*x
    putStrLn "Hello World!" ++ show y
    returnA -< y
```

the arrow syntax complains about the expression not bein an arrow (of course), but even with arrows i get no output

```
 output <- identity -< putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255334/debug-output-of-game-objects-in-haskell-yampa-and-hood

Answer (score 6):

I've only played around with Yampa a bit while trying to work through the FRP papers, but in my understanding this just isn't at all how you work with `IO` in Yampa. Instead you "animate" an `SF a b` with the `reactimate` function, which takes a function of type `b -> IO ()` as its second argument. This function is where things like your `putStrLn` would live, along with any other kinds of rendering the program does.

The "Animating Signal Functions" section of the ["Yampa Arcade"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.8016&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper gives a good explanation of how `reactimate` works.

Comment: so i have to collect all messages and print them in "actuate :: ... IO()"? is there no other way to create output/debug messages? this sounds very hard to debug...

Comment: @sisif: If you just want old-school "printf debugging", that's what `Debug.Trace` is for. For "real" output, the whole idea of FRP libraries is to separate time-varying, interactive logic from IO side effects.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a full Hello World example for Yampa.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import FRP.Yampa

main = reactimate initialize input output process
initialize  = return "Hello World!"
input _     = return (0.0, Nothing)
output _ x  = putStrLn x >> return True
process     = identity
```